# complete or open Kähler  manifold and  simply connected 

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

A complete or open Káhler  manifold with positive definite Ricci 
tensor is simply connected? is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S\subset \mathbb{P}^1$ denote a finite subset consisting of $n\geq 2$ points. The Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{P}^1$ induces a Kahler metric on $X= \mathbb{P}^1\backslash S$ with a positive-definite Ricci tensor. $X$ is open and Kahler, but $\pi_1(X, *)$ is free on $n-1$ generators. Maybe you want to take the manifold to be complete and non-compact? As you probably know, it is a theorem of Kobayashi that a compact Kahler manifold with positive definite Ricci tensor is simply connected.

Comment: Dear Kevin, Thanks for your nice comment. Would you please explain with more details on your counterexample? 

Comment: Do you know the answer to the question if the metric is assumed to be complete (and of course the manifold is noncompact)?

Comment: Dear YangMills. No, if you have any idea please write it

Comment: @Haskell The Fubini-Study metric is well-known to be Kahler with positive-definite Ricci tensor. These properties are local and so are preserved if we restrict to an open subset, e.g. $\mathbb{P}^1$ minus $n\geq 2$ points. This last space is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ minus $n-1$ points, which has the homotopy type of the wedge of $n-1$ circles. From this it follows that $\pi_1$ is free on $n-1$ generators.

Comment: @YangMills I can't think of any, at the moment. A quick Google search didn't turn up much either... 

Comment: Dear Kevin , your comment was very nice

Comment: In Yau's the open problem list, one asks "Is any complete Kahler manifold with positive Ricci curvature is a Zariski open subset of some compact Kahler manifold?" Any connection?